# SQL parameter insert in temp table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have ssrs report which receives multivalued parameter like we can check USA,India,Germany from the checkboxes 
Parameter name is @country

What I need is I need to store the parameter in table in below format

```
Create table #tempcountry
(Name varchar(20))

Insert into #tempcountry values (@country)
```

What I basically need is table has to store values like

```
Name

USA
India
Germany
```

This is my requirement I am struck here can anyone help me out on this??

Comment: You need to split the `@country` via user defined function or inbuilt function to perform insert operation.

Comment: Does you country parameter come from a table in the first place? If it does then just do `INSERT INTO #tempCountry SELECT Country FROM myCountryTable WHERE Country IN (@country)`

Answer (score 1):

In this case the parameter must be a table typed one, passed in READ ONLY mode and having all the data inserted before in a table variable.

Example :

```
CREATE TYPE TYP_COUNTRIES AS TABLE (COUNTRY_NAME VARCHAR(100));
GO
```

The query report must be base on a function or a procedure :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F_T_MyQuery (@CTRY TYP_COUNTRIES READONLY)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT *
        FROM   MyTable
        WHERE  Country_name IN (SELECT * FROM @CTRY);
GO
```

To use it :

```
DECLARE @Countries TYP_COUNTRIES;

INSERT INTO @Countries VALUES ('spain', 'italy', 'france')

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.F_T_MyQuery (@Countries);
```